# Can App Engine cron jobs use https (SSL)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have an App Engine app that requires SSL for access to any URL.

Tasks execute without any issues and required https (SSL).

The cron job I am trying to run also requires SSL (it's checked at the Base Handler level) but it fails to run. I am fairly certain that is the issue because the URL runs fine from a browser using GET but it does require https. I don't really want to have to change the Base Handler (in python) to allow some requests to go through without SSL.

There is no log entry in App Engine logs at the time the job ran (which ran according to schedule).

The status of the job is "failed".

Is there a configuration parameter for App Engine cron jobs to use SSL or is this a feature request of the App Engine team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first read [Securing URLs for Cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron) and then implement some (or all) of the proposed methods, I think that by requiring "admin" permissions for Cron tasks and by checking `X-Appengine-Cron: true` you are getting quite safe even without using SSL.

You don't have to change your Base Handler, just create another handler just for Cron jobs.

Comment: Right. I had read Securing URLs for Cron. I was hoping for a way to run cron jobs with SSL. I guess I will write another handler to check for the cron header. It's just that I wanted to share the URL cron calls with one that can be called from a browser to invoke an immediate update (that requires SSL).This limitation seems artificial since tasks can execute with SSL but cron jobs can't. This will take more (not too much) logic I was hoping to avoid in trying to keep it simple and controlled by configuration and not code.